# Images taking long waiting time IIS 7.5 asp.net 4

Tags: asp.net, iis-7

We have a separate domain for serving static content, we are running on iis 7.5, windows 2008 r2, but images are taking long waiting time before rendering, there by increasing overall page load time. any suggestions to debug the issue, and as we understood, waiting time is the time taken for processing the request, and why should an IIS take time to process an request for image file?

Comment: How large are the images?

Comment: image are ranging from 1KB to 200KB

Answer (score 0):

Please check whether you have any unwanted http handlers or modules installed in your webserver. some might affect static content too. also, for static content, specify expiry and implement gzip compression. these will help you to deliver the content faster